# Android Cloud Printing with No Dialogs

Tags: android, printing, cloud, kiosk

I'm developing a kiosk type Android app and would like to add printing capability. Since it's a kiosk app, the less prompts/pop-ups the users have to do, the better.

I was able to get the new Google Cloud Printing successfully going in my Android app but there are a few screens the users need to go through before printing can happen. 
I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to have things print automatically with no dialogs, the idea would be to pass whatever user selections are needed (paper size, orientation, etc) from preferences.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm developing something very similar and I'm trying to find a solution too.

Comment: What format is the document in?  What about sending the output file as an email that the print service monitors.

Comment: Here's an answer thay may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026804/google-cloud-print-from-android-without-dialog/40107636#40107636

Answer (score 1):

Exact same problem we have! Silently printing without a dialog for my kiosk app, and printing the image to a pre-selected physical size. Both of these are not possible through the platform API, so we built our own library for it: http://www.groundupworks.com/wings/

Comment: How can you do a Silently print with this library? i only see features to share photos.